# How can I send email using python with google workspace

Tags: django, gmail, google-workspace, django-email

I just signed up for the Google workspace business starter because of lots of recommendations from people, I would like to know how possible is it to send email via my backend API using Django, I've searched for it online but nothing comprehensive or direct, try to contact their support but not available.
Thanks in advance

Comment: try this [delegation#python](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#python) swap out admin sdk for the gmail api and then use that to send your emails.

Answer (score 2):

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE= 'path_to_your_json_credential_file'
DELEGATE='youremail@yourcompany.com'  # The service account will impersonate this user. The service account must have proper admin privileges in G Workspace.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/'] # ... or whatever scope(s) you need for your purpose
    




def connect_to_gmail():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    credentials_delegated = credentials.with_subject(DELEGATE)
    gmail = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials_delegated)

    # do whatever you need with it, check the exemple below :
    # new_msg_history_lst = gmail.users().history().list(userId='me',maxResults=3, startHistoryId='1', labelId='INBOX').execute()
    # print(new_msg_history_lst)

    return gmail



 def gmail_send_message(gmail): # not sure it works properly but it's a start for you
        import base64
        from email.message import EmailMessage
        from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
    
        try:
            message = EmailMessage()
            message.set_content('This is automated draft mail')
            message['To'] = 'receiver@email.com'
            message['From'] = 'your@email.com'
            message['Subject'] = 'Automated draft'
    
            # encoded message
            encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()) \
                .decode()
    
            create_message = {
                'raw': encoded_message
            }
            
            send_message = gmail.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=create_message).execute()
            # print(F'Message Id: {send_message["id"]}')
        except HttpError as error:
            print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
            send_message = None
        return send_message
```

For the above code to work it presupposes that  :

- the account is a google workspace account
- you have created a service account, created keys for it, and downloaded them as a json
- you have added the Domain Wide delegation for the service account, and added to it at least the same scopes as in the ones above
- you have enabled the Gmail API

Comment: Thanks alot for the response, What about sending mails out.

Comment: I have edited my previous response, check it out. I also changed the SCOPES.